# Data set with time-series data for visualization exercise

Tags: data-request, large-datasets, visualization

I am trying to find a data set for data visualization purposes. This can be a data set which has only three months of data in it, or a subset of a larger data set. What reputable data sets can you reccomend to me? I tried to search in Kaggle.com , and data.gov.uk but I have not found a dataset which contains a date field. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need a dataset that covers at least 3 months.

Well, how about the '[Data on the daily number of new reported COVID-19 cases and deaths by EU/EEA country](https://www.ecdc.europa.eu/en/publications-data/data-daily-new-cases-covid-19-eueea-country)'?

---

Another example would be a dataset of articles published in a major scientific journal. Let's take the journal *Nature Communications* and look at all publications from 1 August 2021 to 31 October 2021:

https://api.crossref.org/journals/2041-1723/works?filter=from-pub-date:2021-08,until-pub-date:2021-10&cursor=*

There is an open dataset provided by *CrossRef* in a JSON-format; [see the documentation of the CrossRef API](https://github.com/CrossRef/rest-api-doc) so that you find out how to download the data with the cursor etc.